# Loops? I need to figure out how to fix this.

Tags: java

When i run my program and try to add a input. It keeps saying invalid input. Enter again. I know why it did that b/c i added a while loop but that was for inputs less than 1. How can I fix this? I need to display the occupancy rate and the amount of vacant rooms. I am a beginner so I think I have made a stupid mistake. Can somebody help me?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class hotelOccupancy
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      int floors, numFloors, rooms,totalRoomsOccupied,roomsOccupied, vacant;
      double totalRooms;


      System.out.println("Enter number of floors");
      floors = input.nextInt();

      while(floors < 1);
      {
         System.out.println("Invalid input. Enter again");
      }
      floors = input.nextInt(); 

     numFloors = input.nextInt();
     for(floors = 1; floors <= numFloors; floors++)

     {
         System.out.println("Enter number of rooms in floor");
         rooms = input.nextInt();

         while(rooms < 1);
         {
            System.out.println("Invalid entry. Enter again");
         }

         System.out.println("Enter number of rooms occupied for floor" + floors);
         roomsOccupied = input.nextInt();

         totalRoomsOccupied = input.nextInt();
         totalRoomsOccupied = totalRoomsOccupied + roomsOccupied;

     }

     rooms = input.nextInt();
     totalRoomsOccupied = input.nextInt();


     vacant = rooms - totalRoomsOccupied;

     totalRooms = input.nextDouble();
     double occupancyRate = totalRoomsOccupied/totalRooms;

     System.out.println("The number of rooms vacant are" + vacant);
     System.out.println("Then occupancy rate is" + occupancyRate);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to move the `rooms = input.nextInt();` into the `while(rooms < 1)` loop.

Answer (score 0):

`while(floors < 1);` is equivalent to `while(floors < 1){}` so if you enter a number inferior than one, the loop will never end.

You have to take a new input in the while loop (and remove the `;` after the while).

```
while(floors < 1){
      System.out.println("Invalid input. Enter again");
      floors = input.nextInt(); 
}
```

You have to do the same thing for the other while loop (don't forget to remove the `;` after the while too) :

```
while(rooms < 1){
     System.out.println("Invalid entry. Enter again");
     rooms = input.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: ok thank you! also when i am running the program. It is only displaying one input. It is not asking me to enter number of rooms.

Comment: @user2876349 Try to follow your program step by step. 
There is a bunch of error in your program (even if it's compile) because you reuse variables to do some calculations (example : floors in the for loop, `totalRoomsOccupied = input.nextInt();` etc.).